# Firefox navigation issue. fine in IE and Chrome, random scrollbars

Tags: css, xhtml, css-selectors

I have no idea why, but for some reason the top navigation at http://www.wilwaldon.com/crossing/badnav.html creates scroll bars in Firefox 3.6 when you click one of the links. It works fine in IE and Chrome.  I've tried everything and can't find a solution for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like firefox is putting an outline around the image as you click it and this 1px border is then pushing your layout down.

Try the following line in your css #navigation2 {overflow:none;}

You might need #navigation2 a:active {outline:none;}, #navigation2 a:visited {outline:none;} just to be on the safe side

Comment: Thank you, forgot about that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `outline:0` for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `overflow:none;` at     `#navigation2`  CSS block